# how to delete corresponding matching rows in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I'm trying to delete rows in a table only when there is a corresponding entry with a negative amount.  The tricky part is there could be more positive than negative or more negative than positive.

```
value1   amt 
12345    50  
12345    50  
12345   -50  
12345   -50  
abcde    40  
abcde    40  
abcde   -40  
11111    30  
11111   -30  
11111   -30
```

The result should be:

```
abcde    40 
11111   -30
```

Comment: you can do it by 2 steps using PL/SQL script but it will have a bit of a bad performance, what is the table size (rows count) ?

Answer (score 2):

I have to apologize.  I realized the posters data set was too simple.  Here is a revised answer that I believe works.

Basically, you need to partition into pairs and then delete the pairs having sum() = 0.

```
create table t ( id varchar2(20), val number );

delete from t;

INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( '12345', 50);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( '12345', 50);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( '12345', -50);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( '12345', -50);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( 'abcde', 40);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( 'abcde', 40);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( 'abcde', 20);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( 'abcde', 40);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( 'abcde', -40);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( '11111', 30);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( '11111', -30);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( '11111', -30);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( 'aaaaa', 10);
INSERT INTO t ( id, val ) values ( 'aaaaa', -30);

COMMIT;

MERGE INTO t
USING  (WITH value_partition AS
               (SELECT t.*,
                       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY t.id, t.val ORDER BY ROWID) rn_in_value
                FROM   t)
        SELECT sp.ROWID row_id,
               sp.*,
               CASE WHEN SUM (sp.val) OVER (PARTITION BY sp.id, ABS (sp.val), rn_in_value) = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
                 keep_row
        FROM   value_partition sp) u
ON     (t.ROWID = u.row_id
AND     u.keep_row = 'N')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t.val   = u.val
  DELETE
    WHERE  u.keep_row = 'N';

SELECT * FROM t;
```

Comment: what will be the result if you add another row containing "abcde 40" to your example ? according to the question, you might remain with 0,1,2,.. rows containing save id-value

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  (Thanks for not downvoting).  I'm updating my answer now...